# Opening link jsf page/fragement of the commandMenu in a region of the dashboard page fragement or in the inline frame

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have different menu on my dashboard page fragement and using goMenuLink for going to the next page, but when i click on any goMenuLink the page opens in the new tab. Now I want to use commandMenu to navigate to the page/fragement and also want that the menu link page will get open in the center of the dashboard page fragement. How the same can be achieved

How to reload the page or refresh the region or inline frame when user click another commandMenu. I was able to do the same when i made the menu from the task flow by creating the dynamic region and providing the dynamic region link in the menu container but the same is not working with the commandMenu

Answer (score 0):

Create a task flow with the following

1) create page fragment1 add the dashboard content to this page fragment. Place the `af:menu-->af:commadMenuItem` in the center. Use the appropriate layouts to get into center

2) create page fragment 2, add 'af:inlineFrame' and add your page URL o the source attribute of the inline frame

3) provide the value 'go to Fragment 2' to action attribute of command menu item in the fragment 1

4) create the navigation flow between fragment 1 and fragment 2 with outcome value 'go to Fragment2'

At runtime
When you click on the command menu in the fragment 1 , it will take you to the fragment 2 in the same tab.

Comment: @Peddi.view page is opening over the dashboard page containing the menu..I want the the menu linked page fragments will get open in below the menu bar and will get refreshed if usr clicks another menu dont want to navigate to another page but want to open the menu page in the same dashboard page fragment.

Comment: also the page that is opening is not opening properly, source code of the page is rendering in the region instead of the page